# JQ to Parse CSV - How to Skip Headers

Tags: csv, jq

I have a CSV that needs to be converted to a simple new-line separated format to be fed into another script, but running into a weird issue.

Contents of CSV:

```
"1. ID","2. Height","3. Gender","4. Age"
"<1111111111>","5ft. 10.0in.","M"," 15.0"
"<2222222222>","6ft. 0in.","M"," 22.0"
```

Version 1 of CLI command:

```
cat source.csv | sed 's/[\"<>]//g' | ~/projects/dp/vendor/jq/1.5/jq --raw-input --compact-output 'split("\n") | .[1:] | map(split(",")) | map({"phone_number":.[0],"opt_in":"yes"}) | .[]'
```

Version 1 output: None

Version 2 of CLI command:

```
cat source.csv | sed 's/[\"<>]//g' | ~/projects/dp/vendor/jq/1.5/jq --raw-input --compact-output 'split("\n") | .[0:] | map(split(",")) | map({"phone_number":.[0],"opt_in":"yes"}) | .[]'
```

Version 2 output:

```
{"phone_number":"1. ID","opt_in":"yes"}
{"phone_number":"1111111111","opt_in":"yes"}
{"phone_number":"2222222222","opt_in":"yes"}
```

It's my understanding that the .[1:] tells JQ to only parse rows (separated by new line) past row #1, however row #1 will dictate references (being able to reference phone_number).

So why is version 1 not outputting anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1 is missing the `-s` command-line option.

Another way to skip the header row is to use `inputs` without the `-n` command-line option, as follows.  Using `inputs` is also much more efficient than using the `-s` command-line option.

```
< source.csv sed 's/[\"<>]//g' |
jq -cR 'inputs 
      | split(",")
      | {"phone_number":.[0],"opt_in":"yes"}'
```

## Robustness

Using jq to parse a CSV file is fraught with potential difficulties.  In general, it would be better to use a "csv2tsv" tool to convert the CSV to TSV, which jq can easily handle.

Comment: Your revision worked as described, thank you. I agree with not using the -s (slurp) flag especially with larger files, however it's prevalent in many online tutorials.

Comment: `inputs` was included in jq 1.5, which was released on Aug 16, 2015, so ideally those tutorials should be updated.

Comment: Interesting, 1.5 is the version I am using, but as you mentioned a lot of the online tutorials were using the syntax I posted in my question. Thanks again.